# Goutte client save cookies to file

Tags: php, cookies, guzzle, goutte

How to configure the Goutte Client to use a file to store the cookies in a file ? I know that it is a kind of wrapper around GuzzleHttp Client. But I couldn't configure it to save the cookies to a file to reuse them between requests.

Tried to extend the Goutte Client, the method `doRequest` but I don't understand how to do this correctly.

Has anyone used Goutte Client with cookie saving to file ?

Comment: This was a major help for me: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/pull/250#issuecomment-274504635

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an easy way to accomplish this since Goutte forces usage of guzzle's CookieJar class which doesn't persist after script execution. Would have been great to pass your own class to use stuff like FileCookieJar but because of the hardcoded CookieJar call, it isn't possible (someone did create a PR for it but it's been months now and there hasn't been any recent activity inside the Goutte project).

What one could do is create methods that access the BrowserKit CookieJar and store it's contents. Some sample code below:

```
// Will hold path to a writable location/file
protected $cookieFilePath;

public function setCookieFilePath($cookieFilePath)
{
    $this->cookieFilePath = $cookieFilePath;
    if (is_file($cookieFilePath)) {
        // Load cookies and populate browserkit's cookie jar
        $cookieJar = $this->client->getCookieJar();
        $cookies = unserialize(file_get_contents($cookie));
        foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
            $cookieJar->set($cookie);
        }
    }
}

// Call this whenever you need to save cookies. Maybe after a request has been made since BrowserKit repopulates it's CookieJar from the Response returned.
protected function saveCookies()
{
    $cookieFilePath = $this->getCookieFilePath();
    $goutteClient = $this->getGoutteClient();
    $cookieJar = $goutteClient->getCookieJar();
    $cookies = $cookieJar->all();
    if ($cookies) {
        file_put_contents($cookieFilePath, serialize($cookies));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. The idea is great. It's sad that there are no updates for 8 months :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, that worked for me, taken from a [comment by ghost on github](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/pull/250#issuecomment-274504635)

```
<?php
//file to store cookie data
$cookieFile = 'app/cookiejar.txt';

// Start with an empty jar if we don't have any cookies saved yet
$cookieJar = is_file($cookieFile) ?
    unserialize( file_get_contents($cookieFile)) :
    null;

// Initialize the client with the cookie jar
$client = new Client(null, null, $cookieJar);

// Requests and stuff you need to do

// save cookies:
$cookieJar = $client->getCookieJar();
file_put_contents( $cookieFile, serialize( $cookieJar ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect way you can use it:

```php
// Get all cookies
$cookies = $client->getCookieJar()->all();

$cookies = array_map('strval', $cookies); // Cookie::__toString
file_put_contents('cookies.json', json_encode($cookies));
```

To use cookie file:

```php
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\CookieJar;

$client = new Client();
$cookieJar = new CookieJar();
$cookies = json_decode(
    file_get_contents('cookies.json'),
    true
);

$cookieJar->updateFromSetCookie($cookies);

$client = new Client(null, null, $cookieJar);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
public function login()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'site/login');
    $form = $crawler->filter('.btn-success')->first()->form();
    $crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'email@yahoo.com', 
        'password' => 'password'));
    return $client;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).